# How to create Wildcard sub-domains

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla, wildcard-subdomain

I am using joomla 3.3, I have a site on which user can create their own store with domain name so how can I create sub domain by which user can access their sub domain.

Suppose if a user create abc.example.com then that user should be able to access abs.example.com

So how to do this.
i have added these lines to .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.zzphonecase\.com(.*)$ /index.php/%2/%1
```

and these lines in index.php file of template

```
$host = explode ('.', $_SERVER ['HTTP_HOST']);
$subdomain = $host [0];

if((!strcasecmp ($subdomain, 'www')) || (!strcasecmp ($subdomain, 'zzphonecase')))
{
//main site enter code here
}
else
{
//enter code here   
// subdomain

http_response_code (404);
echo 'Error 404 : your domain could not be found';
return false;
}
```

Comment: i have done nothing yet that's why i am asking that how to do i am saving domain name that user creates

Comment: i have no any idea about this ,, yes i have searched it on google but can't understand that how to do it

Comment: can you please help me?

Comment: i have added these lines to .htaccess file
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.zzphonecase\.com(.*)$ /index.php/%2/%1

and these lines in inde.php file of templates

if ((!strcasecmp ($subdomain, 'www')) || (!strcasecmp ($subdomain, 'zzphonecase')))
{

 //main site
} else {
 // subdomain

    http_response_code (404);
    echo 'Error 404 : your domain could not be found';
    return false;
}

Comment: Please add your code to your question in code format so it can easily be read ;)

Comment: ok fine i attached my code that i am using so please check 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when and where you load the domain redirect. you're loading it at the template layer...way too late in the process. it has to be loaded before the joomla framework is loaded (top of root index.php. i use "virtual domains" for multisite domain management, and fabrik for custom forms & components extensively on my sites. you could create a form in fabrik that adds and entry & parameters to the virtual domain database table. little bit of a learning curve on how to execute it, but once you get it this will make it very simple for you. You can then setup your wildcard domain and point it to the site root and let the virtual domains component do all the work for you. Seriously...multisite management in joomla is a real pain. others have done the work for you!